# Button to change Action Bar Style and keep it through app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to Android Development, and I'm creating a simple app to train.

In this app, I would like to have a button in the Action Bar Menu that, if pressed, would change Action Bar color. I somewhat managed to achieve this in my main activity with a static variable and the switchActionBarColor() method listed above. But my problem is when I go to a new activity : the action bar changes color and I did not press the menu button. And when I go back to my main Activity, it is not coloured anymore. I would like the Action Bar style to persist through the application, and I feel my method is not suited at all. What would be the best way to do this, according to you ? Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static int color = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the add_contact button */
public void addContact(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddContactActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.change_color:
            switchActionBarColor();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

protected void switchActionBarColor() {
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

    if (bar == null)
        return ;
    switch (color) {
        case 0:
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_1)));
            break ;
        case 1:
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_2)));
            break ;
        case 2:
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_3)));
            break ;
        case 3:
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_default)));
            break ;
    }
    color++;
    if (color == 4)
        color = 0;
    return ;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save and load the indicator for the color and set the color of the ActionBar in onResume of the Activity.

Comment: Interesting. Will try.